# Angular http response length undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular to interact with jQuery Mobile and create several pages but am running into an issue with the $http service when connecting to my JSON requests. I have a few arrays I'm populating with functions and can bring back data to my pages, except at times I will get errors like this

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

My code looks like this:

```
$http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
  for (i=0; i<data.PROJECT.length; i++)
      $scope.ProjectList.push( { id:data.PROJECT[i].PROJECT_CODE, name:data.PROJECT[i].PROJECT_DESC } );
});
```

My For loop is where it will randomly crash. I've also tried a "then" approach:

```
var request = $http.jsonp(url);
return request.then(function(request) { return request.data.PROJECT; }, handleError );
```

Same error (or no error and blank results). What am I doing wrong? I have each API call in it's own function so it shouldn't be reusing objects (might it be appending them though?). This is part 1; part 2 is separating my code into controller/service - I'm getting these same errors when I do that as well.

**UPDATE**

I've created a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thejame/gce4ns9a/12/) for showing how the values will populate SOMETIMES - run it a few times and you'll notice the arrays take turns returning empty. If you were able to see the console.log output you would see ProjectList contains the resultset of EquipList (in addition to ProjectList) and vice versa.

Comment: What does `data` look like? Try `console.log(data)` in the success callback

Comment: seems like in first case you should use `$http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
  for (i=0; i<data.data.PROJECT.length; i++)` and in second: `return request.then(function(request) { return request.PROJECT;`

Comment: Don't use request object inside your function param..use something different like `res`, In your second call it should be `return request.then(function(res) { return res.data.PROJECT; }, handleError );`

Comment: @pankajparkar, why not?

Comment: @Brennan good idea - I'm seeing weird things in the console. For some reason its stacking my $http requests:

**Object {response: "failure", data: Object, PROJECT: Array[100], EQUIPMENT: Array[100], ACCOUNT: Array[100]}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry SO doesn't let me comment yet :-S so I'll answer here. Based on your

> ... except **at times** I will get errors like this

it sounds like the URL you are calling isn't responding correctly. The code looks good assuming your JSON response looks like this:

```
{
  "PROJECT": [ 
    { "PROJECT_CODE": ..., "PROJECT_DESC": ... },
    ...
  ]
}
```

However if you have this intermittently I would guess that the server responds with something other than this structure above, however still sending a HTTP status `200 OK`.

Try to monitor your network requests and see what the actual response is, or do a `console.log` of `data` inside the `success` function.

--- EDIT

As I thought it mainly is a API issue. The API seems to respond sometimes with the correct list(s), but often times (at least now) it is responding with a `HTTP 200 OK`, but without any data (`Content-Length: 0`). Your fiddle doesn't really show when it's loading, so I updated your code a little bit here:  http://jsfiddle.net/gce4ns9a/15/. The reason why you never have that 'This never shows up' is because the API responds with 'OK' instead of some error code such as `HTTP 500 Inter server error` or something similar.

I hope that helps.

Comment: console.log shows both successes and failures (since I'm having to call these requests 5 times to popular 5 arrays. Oddly they are being stacked, and randomly will take turns failing. Ex:
`Object {response: "success", ACCOUNT: Array[100]}
rambo.js:67` and `Object {response: "failure", data: Object, DEPARTMENT: Array[100], ACCOUNT: Array[100]}`

Comment: There isn't really a lot to work with here, so I would suggest you update your question with more relevant code (you are saying you are population 5 arrays from 5 requests? Please post all of that if possible). Other than that the objects returned clearly define some sort of 'failure', 'success' indication which is not native AngularJS `$http`, so I would suggest you check on that as well. So in your success handler also do an `if (data.response === 'success') { <original for-loop here> }`.

Comment: Thanks @Auke - sorry I'm new to SO and not super fluent with Angularjs yet. I've added a jsFiddle to my original question, hope that helps.

Comment: @James: did you manage to get it to work? I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: yes very helpful. I'm looking at the API and wondering how I can improve its responses, as it seems to be the problem as you said. It's odd because if I just want one response it won't error, but as soon as I try more than one it will possibly return one with no data (but with a 200 status). Testing with Postman, etc. doesn't help because it will always come back OK. I'm going to try rewriting the API returning the JSON objects- I didn't design it so it's taking some time to deconstruct.

Comment: Okay, good to hear it was helpful. Would you mind marking the answer as 'Accepted' if you deemed it helpful enough? (Since I see that you are rather new to the site  )

Comment: I think the problem is still with the API. I'm going to try to rewrite the API and hope that helps. Thanks.